# Ip address of wireless adapter is not showing on ifconfig

Tags: linux, ip, ifconfig

[image]
Even when my wireless adapter is in managed mode it is not showing the ip address of it on ifconfig.

Comment: It is 10.0.2.20, I can clearly see that.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: IMHO,  somebody should post @telcoM’s comments as an answer.

Comment: @Scott Done. I sort of hoped the original poster would have been more active, but looks like it did not work out that way.

Answer (score 3):

Note that it says `Access Point: Not-Associated`, and `ESSID: off/any`. That means you have not yet told the wireless adapter which wireless network it should connect to, and so it hasn't yet connected ("associated" in Wi-Fi terminology) to any network. The network authentication (if applicable) and association are the wireless equivalent of plugging in a network cable. Getting an IP address with DHCP comes after that, not before. **You have missed a step in the connection procedure: double-check the things you've done before this situation.**

Also, modern wireless networks often use WPA2 or even WPA3 authentication, which requires the `wpa_supplicant` or equivalent software to manage the authentication phase. This has been true since the first version of the WPA security. The fact that you are even using `iwconfig` suggests you may be relying on obsolete documentation that might describe connecting to unencrypted ("open") or WEP-encrypted networks. Both `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` are sort of deprecated in modern distributions; the new commands `ip` and `iw` respectively should be preferred.

You're apparently using Kali Linux, which is tailored for doing... unusual things with networks. For this reason, it may have the `wpa_supplicant` disabled by default, as it can interfere with programs designed to spy on wireless network traffic (and possibly attempt attacks on other wireless hosts). If you just want a normal wireless network connection, you'll need to specifically enable it.